# Intellectual property for an app's code

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

I have a software development business and after finishing a client's project i take a copy and put it on my website as a demo for any website visitor to be able to see and play with my previous work without affecting my client's database.

I copied this part from another company's terms and conditions but I want to double check if what's written in there means that i can use the app for any purpose (because it's non exclusive?)

'Subject to the customer’s compliance with all the above terms, AnIdeaForAnApp grants the customer a non­exclusive, irrevocable, perpetual and fee free license to use the software for the purpose which it was intended. This grant is also subject to the customer warranting that it will not, nor will it allow any third party to, separate out the created IP and use it for any other project or purpose, including transplanting that IP into other code, documentation or artifacts'

Answer (score 1):

### No you cannot use it

The relevant part is:

> warranting that it will not, nor will it allow any third party to, separate out the created IP and use it for any other project or purpose

You are using it for another purpose and this is not allowed.

"Non-exclusive" simply means that the person granting the license can grant it to other people (who also can't do what you are doing).

Comment: Gotcha Dale, do you know how I can word it where it would allow me to use it as a demo and not for commercial purposes and at the same time not allow them to take the code and use it for other purpose as well?

Comment: Yes I do: it starts with hiring a lawyer.

Comment: No need to be rude, if you can't help say you can't help.

Comment: Not intended as rudeness: specific legal advice is off-topic for this site.